# How to call this Body class file to another class? Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, class, dart, methods

I got an error, I can't call the body.dart, I've tried to add the method to the profile class but it didn't work, how can I fix the error? thanks.

[image]

Comment: It is better to share your code snippet while asking question.

Comment: hello I'm sorry I forgot to upload the screenshot hehe

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a String value to the constructor.

```
body: Body("Your document ID"),
```